# Trying to start Collector for ArcGIS, can't publish service definition because GIS is on virtual machine with no internet

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, feature-service, arcgis-collector

I'm trying to set up Collector for ArcGIS. We are storing data in databases using SDE. The GIS is stored on a VM with no internet connection. I am trying to figure out how to publish the service definition without internet.. I have saved it as a .SD file and published to our default ArcServer Manager site? localhost:6080/ etc..  It publishes fine on the site but I do not know how to get it to show in Collector app on mobile. It doesn't appear. We have an organizational account and i've created a map but the features are not editable.. i assume it's because they weren't published as feature services. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a feature service with editing enabled. You also need a valid server url and not point to localhost and the service must be accessible to Collector through a wifi connection. Can you use hosted services if you are using an Organizational account or use an ArcGIS Server Feature Service and the field users would vpn in to access the server services?

Comment: I don't know enough to answer every question but am grateful for your response. How do i use a feature service with editing enabled? Is this URL created when we set up the GIS? How do i obtain the URL. The VM has no internet and does not pick up a wifi connection. I don't know if field users would VPN to access the server services. Sorry i am not very helpful

EDIT: I think the field users might be able to VPN to it? As in access the VM the same way i do? Yes i think they might be able to do that. 

i'm not sure the guy who set up the GIS had any of this prepared, such as, the URL..

Comment: With editing enabled you will add it to the map, the map will get flagged that it has an editable layer and collector will open that map. Yup you can configure you server URL when you install ArcGIS Server. The users when they have a connection they would sign into the vpn which will access your internal network, then if you service supports sync they would download a local copy, then disconnect the VPN and collect data, sign back into VPN and sync changes.

Comment: I went into my organizational account and into the webmap and enabled every layer to be editable. I go into the collector app and sign in with the same credentials but I see no maps in there at all.

Comment: Did you resave the map and Are those hosted feature layers?

Comment: I resaved the map and what do you mean hosted feature layers? The way I imported they layers into the org. account map was to save the shapefiles into a zip folder and then import into the map that way.

Comment: You will want to add the layers that are zipped under My Content and check the box to publish as a feature layer, configure your layer so its editable under the item settings. Then you add the publish service to the map, save the map, refresh the gallery in Collector and you will have a map available for data collection.